# Blazor create value in resx-file

Tags: c#, blazor, resx

I try to add a value to my resx file.

```
using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@$".\ResourceFiles\Resource_en.resx"))
        {
            resx.AddResource(value.Trim(), value_translation);
            resx.Close();
        }
```

But when the new value is added the resx file shows the error:

> Invalid ResX input. Valid resheader tags for the ResX reader and writer type names cannot be found.

Comment: What is the contents of the ResX file? The error suggests the ResX format is invalid or malformed in some way.

Comment: I just added a new resx-file , so its empty.

Comment: When you say it's empty, is it a zero-byte file? Or does it contain some metadata?

Comment: I generated with VS2019 a new resource file called Resource_en.resx. When I open it with VS2019 u see the Standard "String1" value. I modified the file to public and that was it.

Comment: So it sounds like at one point after generating the ResX file the format was valid and you were able to open it. At what point did it start showing the error you mentioned in your original question?

Comment: When i create a resx file with vs2019 it works, when i add a value with code above it shows the error directly when i try to open the file

Comment: Could you provide the data you're trying to add to the ResX file (`value.Trim()` and `value_translation`) as a minimally reproducible example? It could be a problem with the data you're trying to store.

Comment: Two Strings "Test1" and "Test2".